# codeIgniter is not working after primary domain to subfolder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, web-hosting

I Purchase new Multi-domain shared hosting plan.

www.example.com is my primary domain(Root domain)

```
public_html/
example
.htaccess
```

i change my primary domain using this code in public_html/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !example/
RewriteRule (.*) /example/$1 [L]
```

now public_html/example is my new primary domain

And i set-up CodeIgniter project in example folder and it is working for `www.example.com/` but not working for `www.example.com/index.php/about` it is return `No input file specified.`

This is my CodeIgniter .htaccess in `public_html/example/.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the **?** sign after index.php in your .htaccess as

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

checkout this [link](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Godaddy-Installation-Tips) for more informaiton.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling like`www.example.com/about`, you are forwarding all requests by default to index.php via .htacess file